# Removing null elements and keeping non-null elements together on a list in jasper reports

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport

I am using JRBeanCollectionDataSource as datasource for a subreport.  Each record in the list contains elements with either null or non-null value .  This is my POJO:

```
public class PayslipDtl {

        private String earningSalaryHeadName;
        private double earningSalaryHeadAmount;

        private String deductionSalaryHeadName;
        private double deductionSalaryHeadAmount;

        String type;

public PayslipDtl(String salaryHeadName,
            double salaryHeadAmount, String type) {
        if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("Earning")) {
            earningSalaryHeadName = salaryHeadName;
            earningSalaryHeadAmount = salaryHeadAmount;
         } else { 
            deductionSalaryHeadName = salaryHeadAmount;
            deductionSalaryHeadAmount = salaryHeadAmount;
        }
    }

        //getters and setters
        }
```

Based on the "type", the list is populated as such: {"Basic", 4755, null, 0.0}, {"HRA", 300, null, 0.0}, {null, 0.0, "Employee PF", 925}, {"Medical Allowance", 900, null, 0.0} and so on...

After setting isBlankWhenNull to true and using "Print when" expression, the record is displayed as such:

```
|Earning            |Amount|Deduction            |Amount|
--------------------|------|---------------------|------|
| Basic             | 4755 |                     |      |
| HRA               | 300  |                     |      |
|                   |      | Employee PF         |  925 |
| Medical Allowance | 900  |                     |      |
| Fuel Reimbursement| 350  |                     |      |
|                   |      | Loan                | 1000 |
---------------------------------------------------------
```

I want it to be displayed as such:

```
|Earning            |Amount|Deduction            |Amount|
--------------------|------|---------------------|------|
| Basic             | 4755 |  Employee PF        |  925 |
| HRA               | 300  |  Loan               | 1000 |
| Medical Allowance | 900  |                     |      |
| Fuel Reimbursement| 350  |                     |      |
---------------------------------------------------------
```

Setting isRemoveLineWhenBlank to true doesn't work since it is not the entire row which is blank but only a subset of elements of a row that is null.

Is it possible in Jasper?

I am using iReport Designer 5.0.1 with compatibility set to JasperReports3.5.1.

Comment: Not sure whether this is precisely what you are after, but wouldn't it be easier to split this into two tables, one for the Earnings and one for the Deductions? You could position them next to each other to achieve the effect you want?

Comment: @RoryB Do you mean two separate lists - That would mean using two subreports, right?  Or did you mean using the same list.. Can you tell me how this can be done because I have never used tables in Jasper before.  I want to limit subreports to a minimum since I am going to a use few other subreports in the same report and it causes various alignment/position issues for other elements below it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a List component for the deduction/amount, [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hl_VyvpaiCo) you have a video tutorial on how to do this.

Then deduction and amount fields on the list component need the following options Blank when null and Remove line when blank.

If this still gives you blank lines, try putting both fields on a frame inside the list and mark those options for the frame too.

Answer (score 0):

Only one good solution is, you have to create separate table as:

```
table employeeED:
srno int,
Earning varchar(50),
EarnAmount Double,
Deduction varchar(50)
DedAmount Double
```

then you have to insert all earnings in earning side and update all deductions in deductions side.

```
    int i=1;
    rs.first();
    while(rs.next())
    {
         if(rs.getString("type").equals("Earning"))
            Insert into employeeEd (srno, Earning,EarnAmount) values     (i, rs('earning'), rs('eamt'))
    }

    int j=1;
    rs.first();
    while(rs.next())
    {
        if(rs.getString("type").equals("deduction"))
           update employeeEd set Deductions='"+rs('earning')+"',  DedAmount=" + rs('eamt') + " where srno="+j)
        j++;
    }
```

then use employeeED table as datasource.
100% working.